# To put a point at infinity

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

In physics, we say that we can put points at infinity in order to compactify some manifolds, like compactifying the plane via the stereographic projection. But, in order to do this, we also need to add a point at infinity.
To map the plane to the sphere we use the aforementioned projection. But, how do we naturally include the extra point at infinity? Do we do it in a forced way by just defining a point as the point at infinity? If so, how exactly?
Lastly, since infinity is not a number (so it cannot correspond to a point, but correct me if I am wrong), how can we assign a point to it? How can we intuitively think of adding a point at infinity?

Thank you.

Comment: You can in general create a "one-point" compactification of any topological space. It is not necessarily the case that the one-point compactification of a manifold is not always a manifold.

Comment: When we do the one point compactification of the complex plane, we have to define how we analyze numbers at infinity. If we want to analyze a holomorphic function $f$ at infinity, we analyze the function $f(1/z)$ at $0$. There are tricks to get around actually using infinity as a number, at least in complex analysis.

Comment: Infinity is not a number, but neither is $(3,4)$, a point on a plane. A point is an object, not a quantity.

Comment: We just do it. You have a set. Set theory guarantees there's something out there that the set doesn't include. You toss it in and create a slightly larger set. We call the new point "infinity". And if there's a topology involved, we extend the topology in a systematic way, usually a one-point compactification.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. So, how do we actually do it?

Comment: Adjoining a point is not a problem, theoretically. However, it can be done in many ways, most of which are uninteresting. One of the ways that are usually interesting is dubbed "at infinity", not because that phrase has a previous, strictly defined meaning, but because the way the point is adjoined intuitively corresponds to how we feel infinity should behave if we tried to force it into our space somewhere.

Comment: It's easy to overthink what's actually happening. In my opinion, a better name for "adding a point at infinity" would've been better named "invite Santa Claus to the party". But one saying got entrenched before the other did.

Comment: In complex analysis, the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_line#Complex_projective_line:_the_Riemann_sphere) $\mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\} = P^1(\mathbb{C})$ is obtained by saying : $f$ is analytic (holomorphic) at $z=\infty$ iff $f(1/z)$ is holomorphic at $z=0$. It defines implicitly a *complex topology* on the neighborhood of this new point. Allowing us to consider holomorphic functions $P^1(\mathbb{C})\to P^1(\mathbb{C})$, and those are exactly the quotients of polynomials (the rational functions).

Comment: In  stereographic projection , the point at infinity is approached closer and closer as you move further from the origin...

Comment: This [animation loop](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/images/gallery-1.2/anim/stereo_proj.gif) of a rotating hemisphere under stereographic projection (too large to upload) may be of interest.

Comment: Despite the popular misconception, there *are* several numbers that commonly go by the name of "infinity". What *is* true is that no "complex  number" goes by that name.

Answer (score 10):

Topologically, the way to put a point *somewhere* in particular is to define which sets are its neighborhoods. If you know all the open sets containing a point, then you know "where" the point is.

To add a point at infinity, the usual trick is to say that we adjoin one point to the underlying set, and then define its open neighborhoods as the complements of existing compact sets. This trick captures the intuitions that we want to have about "infinity". Think of it this way: exteriors of larger and larger discs centered at the origin (or anywhere else) are smaller and smaller neighborhoods of infinity. This captures the idea that compact sets are *bounded away from infinity*.

If you project the plane onto a sphere via the stereographic, then you can see that exteriors of such circles actually map to smaller and smaller open discs around the missing point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But, how do we actually do it? I mean, how do we write it down(for example, for the stereographic projection)

Comment: How do you do any topological construction? You just define it, and you can work with it. I'm not sure I'm getting the weight of your "how"...

Comment: So, we just define the extra point? What I don't really get is how will we give one such point coordinates. For example, for the stereographic projection, we map the points of the sphere to points on the plane and we instantly know which point(with its coordinates) on the sphere maps to a point on the plane(with its coordinates). So, how can we take,say, the north pole of the sphere and map it to the plane if we can't give it coordinates on the plane?

Comment: In the case where your starting space is a line, or a plane, there's a nice way to visualize the resulting space. In more abstract cases, you just define it. If the original space is the set $X$ with a topology defined, then the new space is the set $X\cup\{\infty\}$, where $\infty$ is the name of the new point, and the new topology is just the pre-existing topology on $X$, plus some new open sets which are $(X\setminus K) \cup \{\infty\}$ where $K$ is any set that is compact in $X$.

Comment: Ah, coordinates. Not every space can be endowed with coordinates, and a point at infinity isn't going to have coordinates that are real numbers. That's kind of the point of calling it "infinity". It's the point that you haven't reached yet if you stop at any real number, in any direction.

Comment: So, how would we identify the "mapping" of the north pole in the plane? Just by saying that north pole is mapped to the point "$\infty$"?

Comment: Yeah, that works. You're not going to visualize it at any particular place in the plane, but you could imagine a sort of circle of infinite radius "around" the plane, and then say it's just one point.

Comment: Aaah, thanks! Great! I appreciate that you put some time to explain it to me.

Comment: A handy "point" not in $X$ (in a well-founded, material set theory) is $X$ itself... so we can always take $\infty\equiv X$ producing $X\cup\{X\}$. This is a concrete realization of one of Robert's comments. You (TheQuantumMan) may feel that $X$ is not a "point", but the idea is that what "points" generally are is not important to the notion of a topological space, and, within the context of a typical set theory like ZFC, everything is a set, so $X$ is a set of sets, and $X$ is also a perfectly fine set itself.

Answer (score 7):

One way to do it consists in considering the (affine) *real plane* as the (affine) *complex line*.

A point on this line is just a given complex number $z$. The one-point compactification is obtained considering the (affine) *complex plane* $\mathbf C^2$. We have a map
\begin{align}\mathbf A^1(\mathbf C)=\mathbf C&\longrightarrow \mathbf A^2(\mathbf C)=\mathbf C^2\\
z&\longmapsto (z,1)\end{align}
Now we define an `equivalence relation` on $\mathbf C^2\smallsetminus\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}$:
$$(z,u)\sim (z',u')\overset{\text{def}}{\iff}\exists\lambda\in\mathbf C^*, z'=\lambda z, u'=\lambda u.$$
This means all points in $\mathbf C^2$, different from the origin, in the complex subspace $\langle(z,u)\rangle$ are equivalent to $(z,u)$.

The *projective complex line* $\;\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$ is, by definition, the `quotient set` $ \bigl(\mathbf C^2\smallsetminus\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}\bigr)/\sim$, endowed with the `quotient topology`. One shows $
\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$ is a *compact space*.

A point in $\;\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$ is denoted $[z:u]$. The above map, composed with the canonical map 
\begin{align}
\mathbf C^2\smallsetminus\bigl\{(0,0)\bigr\}&\longrightarrow\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)\\
(z,u)&\longmapsto [z:u]
\end{align}
 yields the map
\begin{align}
\mathbf A^1(\mathbf C)\bigr\}&\longrightarrow\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)\\
z&\longmapsto [z:1],
\end{align}
and any (projective) point$[z:u]$ `such that` $u\ne 0$ is the canonical image of the unique point $z/u\in \mathbf A^1(\mathbf C)$, since $\;(z,u)\sim (z/u,1)$.

What if $u=0$? All points $(z,0)$ are equivalent, hence yield a unique  point in $ \mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$. We call it the *point at infinity* of the affine (complex) line.

To sum up:
$$\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)=\mathbf A^1(\mathbf C)\cup\{\infty\}.$$

Comment: I believe this to be the best answer. It gives a concrete way to calculate with the point at infinity. It might be worth mentioning how to move from one coordinate chart to another coordinate chart, just to get the point across. ;)

Answer (score 6):

How do you throw a bunch of paper together into some binding and get a book? How do you toss a fish into a bowl of water and get a fish bowl? How do you add espresso into some hot milk and get a latte?

The thing you throw in has nothing to do with the original collection. At all. And you're not trying to interpret the thing you added as somehow "the same" as the collection that was originally there. But the thing you throw into the collection creates a new thing altogether that gets its own new name.

The "point at infinity" is the binding, the fish, the espresso. The "one-point compactification" is the book, the fish bowl, the latte.

Comment: Thanks for the intuition. Following your comment from above which has to do with set theory, could you please extend it via an example in your answer? I think it would be really helpful for me in order to get a more concrete picture now that I have the intuition

Comment: The real numbers are the papers. "$\infty$" or "Infinity" (this is just a name, it could equally be called Santa Claus or Toby) is the binding. The set $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is putting the papers inside the binding. Extending the topology on the reals to a new topology on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is stitching the papers together with the binding. The result is the book, or more formally, the "one-point compactification of the reals".

Comment: Great! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 6):

Based on your comments, I think I can pinpoint some aspects which might interest you.

As was mentioned several times, the construction is simple: you pick a point $p$ not in the manifold, and define its neighbourhoods as complements of compact sets. The resulting space $\widetilde{M}=M \cup \{p\}$ with the topology generated by this process is called the *one-points compactification* of $M$ (or [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension)).

This is a general process in a sense: one can prove that it works comfortably in any locally compact Hausdorff topological space which is not compact. However, there is an issue: it may result in something which is **not** a manifold, **even if your original space was a manifold**.

Thus, your quest to search coordinates for this compactification in the comments may be in vain.

For example, consider two disjoint open intervals as the manifold $M$. The one-point compactification of such space is homeomorphic to a figure-eight, which is not a manifold. You may think that this is simply an artifact of $M$  not being  connected, but it isn't: take $M$ an open cylinder. The one-point compactification of it is homeomorphic to a horn torus, which is also not a manifold.